# Android: looper/handler vs. Java Observer?

Tags: java, android, handler, observer-pattern, looper

Aren't these competitors?  I'm thinkin they're not, but don't see it.

How about within the context of an Activity needing to learn when a Service has new xyz?

Thanks!

Comment: By competitors you mean two different ways to accomplish the same thing? They do have slightly different purposes.. the looper is to help you create a message loop, the observer is to let you get state updates on an object you are observing.  Its really not clear what your question is though..

Comment: And the purpose of a Looper is to handle an asynchronous Message  ... just as an Observer handles an asynchronous Observable.  My question is, why use a looper/handler?

Comment: Observer callbacks aren't necessarily asynchronous, it's just a way of decoupling components. With a handler, messages are processed on the current thread at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

They are for different purpose so you can't compare in the way that one exclude the other as perhaps you may intend. I explain:

- Registered **Observers** receive notification of a change *all together* sequentially simply calling *once* `notifyObservers(..)`.
- **Handlers** allow you to modify UI components from a background thread but you handle/update *only 1* "observer" (the one handled by the Handler).

More advanced, if you think, you can even combine the two, to always be exception free while update UI from a background thread still keeping the Observer pattern.

I think nobody answered you in these 5 years because almost nobody is aware of great power of Observer pattern ;-)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how these two patterns can be combined? For example, if I have a UI, an Observer for this UI, a Handler that process some request initiated from this UI, and a Network component that get the actual response to this request. What is the flow if I want to combine these two patterns? Thanks!